# If no name, show username

Tags: php, drupal

Doing some maintenance work for an old website. There is area where I would like to display user's `full name` if it is entered, otherwise, display user's `username`. I dont know why the following code didn't work, I did not get any error messages.

```
    <?php
global $user;
$uid = user_load($user->uid);
$myprofile = 'main';
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($uid, $myprofile);

$display_name = $profile-> field_main_first_name['und'][0]['value'] &" "& $profile-> field_main_last_name['und'][0]['value'];

if(empty($display_name)){
    echo $display_name = $user->uid;
}

echo $display_name
?>
```

Comment: The PHP concatenation operator is `.`, not `&`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I got it from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following did the trick for me.

```
    <?php
global $user;
$uid = user_load($user->uid);
$myprofile = 'main';
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($uid, $myprofile);

$first_name = $profile-> field_main_first_name['und'][0]['value'];
$last_name = $profile-> field_main_last_name['und'][0]['value'];

if (empty($first_name)) {
    $display_name = $user->name;
  } else {
    $display_name = $first_name." ".$last_name;
  };
?>
```

Comment: You might want to consider using the [null coalescing operator `??`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) to avoid possible undefined index errors on the assignment of `$first_name` and `$last_name` e.g. `$first_name = $profile-> field_main_first_name['und'][0]['value'] ?? '';`